# devise authentication with emberjs

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, api, ember.js, devise

I use devise for authentication in my rails app
I am building an ember js application which contact with my rails api 
my devise.rb

```
Devise.setup do |config|

  config.mailer = "Devise::Mailer"

 require 'devise/orm/active_record'

 config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]
  config.http_authenticatable = [:token]
 config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]

 config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth, :token_auth]

  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10
  config.confirmation_keys = [ :email ]


 config.sign_out_via = :delete


end
```

and my session controller

```
module Api
 class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

def create
 unless params[:email] && params[:password]
   return invalid_params('You need to provide both email and password')
 end

 res = User.find_for_database_authentication(email: params[:email])

 if res && res.valid_password?(params[:password])
  user = res
end
unless user
 unless params[:email] && params[:password]
 return invalid_params('invalid email or password')
 else
   return invalid_params('You need to provide both email and password')
  end 
else
  sign_in user,:store=>false
  user = warden.authenticate!
  user.ensure_authentication_token!

render json: current_user ,serializer: UserSerializer ,status: 201
 end
 end


 def destroy
signed_out = (Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name))
 render json: {}, status: :accepted
end
protected

def invalid_params(errorMessage)
warden.custom_failure!
render json: { errorMessage: errorMessage }, status: 403

 end
end
end
```

every thing works fine when I authentication with my ember app to sessions/sign_in and json return the current_user credintials

but in my profiles controller I have before filter

```
module Api
  class ProfilesController < ApplicationController


 before_filter :auth_only?

respond_to :json


 def index


  @profiles =Profile.all
 respond_with(@profiles)

 end

end 
 end
```

in my application controller

```
     def auth_only?
unless user_signed_in?
render  json: {},status: 401
end
end
```

the problem that when I tried to fetch profiles.json in my ember app ...it gives me unauthorized 401

my auth.js in ember

```
 $.ajaxSetup({

beforeSend: function(xhr, options) {

    var encoded_auth_token, header;
    if (Remon.Auth.get('auth_token')) {
        encoded_auth_token = Base64.encode64(Remon.Auth.get('auth_token') + ":X");
        header = "Basic " + encoded_auth_token;
         xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', header);

    }else{
        console.log("not auth");
    }
},
error: function(xhr) {
    if (xhr.status === 401) {

        console.log("unauth");
    }
    if (xhr.status === 404) {
         console.log("wrong");
    }
}
});
```

I am using devise 2.1.2 and ember 1.4

also in my request headers no authorization headers found inspite I am setting it also I get it from the console via Remon.Auth.get("auth_token")

[image]